# Strategy of passing and returning values (any kind, including array or more complex data structure)?

Tags: c++, return-value

I used to use PHP, and I like the way PHP passes and returns values, very straightforward.

Now I've turned to C++ to gain more performance, but find it difficult to pass and return 2d array, not to mention some more complex data structures.

- I once thought JSON may be a choice, but this way you have to encode and decode every time, not practical.
- Currently I am using pointers, but it's not very convenient.
- Then I tried STL vector, still not satisfied,the STL vector is a little safer and comfortable to use, but still, you have to manually iterate the array, what I want is a more flexible strategy to deal with these kind of tasks
- I tried to use class/struct to hold the data, then pass and return, but I have to define a new struct whenever to pass a different kind of data structures.

So, what's the best choice for data exchanging between functions? 
Professionals, any suggestions?

edit:

As an example:

```
string function(string data){

//do something

return result;

}
```

If this result is like:

```
{
  "key1"=>{"key11"=>"value1"},
  "key2"=>{"key21"=>"value2"},
  "key3"=>{"key31"=>"value3","key32"=>"value32"}
}
```

it would be too complicated to pass this with pointers, wouldn't it?
With php, you can use several foreach statements to process the nest array easily.

edit2:

To put it simply, how to exchange a nested array with unknown length and dimension?

edit3:

I am trying to find the cpp way of dealing with common programming tasks. And exchange data between functions is very important.

- In php, I can easily process the nested array with several foreach and return array easily.
- But with cpp

  - I have to return the result array pointer or directly operate the referred vector
  - i need to pass the array length to functions
  - when data structure is complicated, get values from the array is difficult.

Comment: I suggest you to read a textbook.

Comment: You call functions knowing what type of data they return and how to work with that type of data. If functions return proper types and sensible values (such as empty lists rather than null) it is trivial to use them, as you know (if we follow that example) you can always iterate over the returned list, it might just be a list of none.

Comment: @Abyx I am reading a textbook called: C++ How to Program, Fifth Edition By H. M. Deitel. But can not find the answer.

Comment: Seems you want to have your cake and eat it. A major reason for the better efficency of cpp is it's strong typing. I'm sure it takes some adjusting to, but I think that's what you have to do rather than trying to carrying on programming as if you were still using PHP.

Comment: @thecoshman currently i can deal with most basic circumstances, like int, char, string, 1d array, 2d array, vectors, but what if you want to return someting like {"key1"=>{"key11"=>"value1"},"key2"=>{"key21"=>"value2"}},or even more complicated?

Comment: And I can not find the question. `array2d f(array2d)` - this is the best way to pass a 2d array into a function and return it from it.

Comment: "still not satisfied"? What the hell does this mean?

Comment: @user2758004 what does that even mean? A map of maps of strings?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes the STL vector is a little safer and comfortable to use, but still, you have to iterate the array, what i want is a more flexible strategy to deal with these kind of tasks.

Comment: @thecoshman It's just an example. To show that in some situations you don't know about the result array info, the length might be variable, the dimension might be different. Put simply, a nested array with unknown length and dimension.

Comment: @user2758004: The length being variable is fine- that's what `std::vector<T>` is for. The dimension being variable is not.

Comment: @john I understand that, I am trying to find the cpp way to deal with common programming tasks, and passing and returning data is very important. But i find it difficult to pass complex data structure with  cpp, i know there must be some way of doing this, so i turned to you for help...

Comment: Your question (before I edited it) referred to "cpp". The language is called "C++". The name "cpp" is ambiguous; it can also refer to the C preprocessor. And there's no need to refer to the language name in your title; that's what tags are for.

Comment: @user2758004 The example you quoted to thecoshman looks like a `std::map` are you familiar with that data structure?

Comment: @join you are right, i am a novice, still not familiar with STL map... in php, i deal everything as array or nested array, or like json...

Comment: "*Then I tried STL vector, still not satisfied*" -- You're going to need to be a lot more specific. We might be able to help you with coding problems; we can't address your lack of satisfaction.

Comment: @user2758004 you need to learn how to design complex data structures in C++ first (learn how to use classes, and how to use the standard containers, to start). Passing them is easy: `f(complex_data_structure)`. Returning them is easy too: `return complex_data_structure;`. That said, I don't often find myself needing really complex data structures very often. I honestly don't know when was the last time I needed a nested map.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I did used classes/struct to do that, but you will have to define a new struct whenever you need to pass a different kind of data structures, that's not convenient. Is there any more flexible way of doing this?

Comment: @user2758004 if you take anything from this page, take this: flexibility and performance are often at odds with each other. If you push too much towards one, you will lose the other. Sometimes you can sorta have both, but in general you can assume that the less flexible you make something, the more performant it is, and vice-versa. C++ has a generic programming tool (templates) that helps in providing both flexibility and performance, but you really can't learn how to use those from an answer on Stack Overflow as they are one of the most complex (and most powerful) parts of C++.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes That's an excellent view! maybe php payed it's price of losing performance to be more convenient... I am now trying hard to adapt myself to the c++ way. You are right, perhaps i need to read more professional textbooks rather than asking newbie questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole "Any kind" thing is really not C++. The language is not intended to support this. Each individual function can only return one kind of thing. You can use something like boost::variant, which can be one of a number of types, or boost::any, which can be any type but it's not very convenient to use. Of course, if you turned to C++ for *performance*, this isn't going to help that matter- the knowledge of the kinds in advance is one of the key factors improving C++ performance.

So I would suggest that instead, you simply learn to deal with strong static typing.

Comment: ok, i know that cpp/java are strong typing language, i am not trying to mess my previous php experience with cpp, instead, i am trying to find the cpp way to deal with common programming tasks. and exchange data between functions is very important. in php, i can easily process the nested array with serveral foreach, but with cpp, i find it complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
map<string, map<string, string>> magic;
magic["key1"]["key11"] = "value1";
magic["key2"]["key21"] = "value2";
magic["key3"]["key31"] = "value3";
magic["key3"]["key32"] = "value32";
```

Comment: that might be a solution, i am a novice, still not familiar with STL map... thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: If you're "still not familiar with STL map", what are you still doing here? Go fix that.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes, sir! Learning STL map...